# Legibility of "of someone's failure to do"

Tags: readability

Is the text in bold clear enough to read and understand?

> The lawyer did not utter the rationale **of the second complainant's failure to complete** his application for leave to apply to the Federal Court.

If I use the phrase "of someone's failure to do" in the other turn of speech, will it remain readable?

> In case of **the second complainant's failure to apply to** the appropriate authority at the agreed time, one should....

Comment: Yes but I'd prefer "explain" instead of "utter the rationale of".

Comment: The whole sentence requires quite a bit of mental juggling to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Someone's failure to do" is grammatically correct, and is fine to read.

Your first example sentence is not easy to read, mainly because it is far too long. It would be easier to read the following:

> The second complainant should have filled out an application, which would have allowed him to apply to the Federal Court. The lawyer did not explain why the second complainant had failed to do so.

Your second example sentence is easy to read.

Comment: I supplemented the question with some information. Thanks.